Why can't I export my HTTP request to cURL in JMeter
Using the latest version of JMeter (5.6.3), I was able to import a cURL command, but I've been struggling to export my HTTP request to cURL format. However, it seems like the option to "Copy as cURL" isn't available. I've tried right-clicking in the "View Results Tree" listener, but there's no such option there.
Am I missing something obvious, or is this feature just not available anymore? It’s a bit frustrating, as being able to quickly grab a cURL command would make testing outside of JMeter so much easier.
Is there a plugin or a simple workaround I can use to export HTTP requests to cURL without constructing the command manually every time?

As of JMeter 5.6.3 there is no such an option
You can request an enhancement via JMeter issue tracker and if there would be enough votes the feature will be implemented in one of the future releases.
You can enable JMeter debug logging for Apache HttpComponents by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />

and then construct your cURL request from jmeter.log file
Alternatively you can use i.e. Burp Suite as the proxy for JMeter, it will intercept all outgoing requests and you will be able to replay them individually as they are or with changes and there will also be "Copy as curl command" context menu entry there
